# How should I implement non-event-based actions in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I come from a couple years' background in looped game programming. I'm very used to having a constant loop in my application which continually calls functions like Update and Draw, allowing me to perform actions like animations over time by incrementing values a bit each frame.

Now that I've got a job involving WPF, though, I find that I was too reliant on that system. Maybe I've got a limited feel for WPF, but it seems like everything is event-based. User clicks a button, you inform the code, the code manipulates values. The values change, code informs UI, UI updates layout. It works well for GUI-based application programming but I find that when I encounter situations which would be trivial in loop-based game programming I am stuck, unable to find a good way to implement simple behaviors.

At the risk of being too vague I'll provide my current problem as an example. After Windows 8 was unveiled I became very enamored with the idea of Semantic Zoom. After playing around with the Start Screen extensively I began working on a port of Semantic Zoom to WPF4.0 for Microsoft Surface (I work with the Surface at my job). I just want a trivial example of it which would allow me to use pinch gestures to navigate up and down in a stack of views.

After many hours spent trying to understand manipulation events (I won't go into that... bleh), I've finally got my view scaling based on a pinch gesture. If it scales past a certain point I jump back to the 'zoomed out' view. Pretty cool. But, the problem is, if the user doesn't complete the gesture and decides not to zoom out, I'm left with a smaller view. I want to animate the scale of the view to constantly 'rebound' from user pinching and restore to a scale of 1. I know if this were loop based I'd just Lerp toward 1 each frame. But since WPF is all based on events, I'm a little lost.

There's probably an answer to this specific problem using inertia or different manipulation events (and I'd be happy to hear it), but in addition I'd just like to know how I can re-orient my mindset to work more effectively in WPF. Is it just about knowing which events to subscribe to? Are there clever ways to use Animations to do what I want? Should I use threads to accomplish these kinds of tasks, or is that cheating (it seems unreliable, plus I'm shaky on threads in WPF)?

This issue is one of my biggest barriers to being effective in WPF, I think (well, this and not quite knowing MVVM yet, working on that). I'd like to see it torn down and be able to be effective in more than just loop-based games programming.

Answer (score 0):

Although i'm pretty sure that most of what you want to do can be done in an event-based manner, you might want to take a look at the MSDN [How to: Render on a Per Frame Interval Using CompositionTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx). Please also note the final section *Per-Frame Animation: Bypass the Animation and Timing System* in [Property Animation Techniques Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970492.aspx).

Comment: Any result with this suggestion?